# Treewidth after merging two low treewidth graphs

Tags: graph-theory

Suppose we have a graph $G$ with [treewidth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Treewidth) $k$, and another graph $G'$ with treewidth $k'$. Then, suppose we "merge" the graphs by identifying two vertices $v$ and $v'$ where $v \in V(G)$ and $v' \in V(G')$. What can we say about the treewidth of the resulting graph $H$?

For instance, is it then true that the treewidth of $H$ is at most $k+k'$ (or maybe even $\max\{k,k'\}$)? Does this follow easily by some known fact?

Comment: If $k = k' =1$ then the identification results in graph of treewidth 1 (as they were both trees to begin with and the resulting graph is a tree). the $k +k'$ bound should come easily from considering tree decomposition. I'm not sure if that can be improved much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is just max(k,k') (assuming the two graphs do not share other vertices, otherwise the merge does not make sense).

Let $T_1,T_2$ be the two trees corresponding to tree decompositions of the two graphs and let $B_1,B_2$ be bags of $T_1,T_2$ containing $v,v'$ respectively. Then a tree decomposition for the merged graph is obtained by simply adding an edge between $B_1$ and $B_2$, as you can verify from the definition.